# Google drive return empty files

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am making a app which access files from google drive. I am using [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#examples) link to acess the files from google drive. The method`Files.List request = service.files().list();` return {} for me all the time. i am posting my all code here.

```
private Drive getDriveService() {
    try {
        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential
                .usingOAuth2(MainActivity.this, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
        credential.setSelectedAccountName("Sachinkamboj1989@gmail.com");

        drive = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
        drive.children();
        drive.files();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    retrieveAllFiles1(drive);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return drive;

}

private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles1(Drive service)
        throws IOException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Files.List request = service.files().list();

    do {
        try {
            FileList files = request.execute();
            System.out.println(files);
            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
        }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null
            && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
    // System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

Method to access file is

Comment: I would recommend you to use android API for google drive. Not this one

Comment: @Nabin Can i access all file to show in my app list using these apis ? please give me suitable link for this.

Comment: That depends on how you have taken OAuth from console.developers.google.com. 

Study this https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/tree/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo

Comment: Can i access file list using this demo to show list in my app UI?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nabin, I will appreciate your answer.

Comment: Be careful with the Google Drive Android API. Make sure you understand all of its restrictions and behvaiors before making a decision to switch. Esp. "Note: The Android Drive API only works with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope. This means that only files which a user has opened or created with your application can be matched by a query."

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks for reply. I want to access every file either created through app or web. How i can do this? Please give a good link if possible.

Comment: @pinoyyid We need to access only one folder data.

Comment: Are the files created by your app, or by the user in drive.Google.com?

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks for reply "using drive.Google". "We wants to show folder or file in the list ". As user will click on any folder then we can 1) Either access all files and folder of this folder in app list 2) Or we can navigate to goggle drive app.

Comment: Are the files (a) created by your app, or (b) by the user in drive.Google.com? Please answer 'a' or 'b'.

Comment: @pinoyyid  answer is b .

Comment: in that case you can NOT use Google Drive Android API

Comment: @pinoyyid Tell me the other best way please.

Comment: @pinoyyid How is possible then? it will be highly appreciate for me.

Comment: getting Drive working from Android is not straightforward because of the OAuth, but it can be done. You just need to work through the docs and sample code, making you sure you;re understanding it and not just copy/paste/pray.

Comment: Can we use with same drive api or any other way?

Comment: @Sirconrad I had the same requirement. I could load all the file with https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive permossion.